# Unexpected Performance Behaviour for Mongodb Lookup Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I am attempting to write an aggregation pipeline for a messaging-system data export, and it involves a bit of lookup pipeline nesting. I am currently experiencing performances that contradict what I expect. The following query seems to take a very long time to run (if it even does complete):

```
conversations.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "messages",
            "let": {"convo_id": "$_id"},
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$eq": ["$conversation_id", "$$convo_id"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$sort": {
                        "created": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "users",
                        "localField": "user_id",
                        "foreignField": "_id",
                        "as": "user"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$unwind": {
                        "path": "$user",
                        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as": "messages"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            ...
        }
    }
])
```

**However** if I move the `$sort` stage so that the `$lookup` and/or `$unwind` stages come before it, the query runs instantly. I also checked the output results, and it seems to all be correct (this leads me to believe it is actually processing the sort stage, and not just ignoring it).

This is contradictory to the behaviour I expected. I would expect that having the `$sort` stage after `$match` and before `$lookup` and `$unwind` would run quicker, but the opposite seems to occur. I'm wondering if anyone may have insight on why this happens.

Comment: You can check the explain plan and see if an index is used in the match& sort stages. `conversations.explain().aggregate([...`